# Website default to apache page after upgrading to apache from 2.4.17 to 2.4.25

Tags: apache, ubuntu

I've upgrade apache2 in order to take advantage of HTTP2.

But now I get the default Apache Ubuntu page when I try to access any of my websites ! - they are configured in separate vhost files in `/etc/apache2/sites-available`

For example :  https://www.pretty-story.com/

Can someone tell me what could be the cause of this ? It's probably a simple configuration change, but I don't where to look at and I'm in panic mode.

Comment: Did you keep your config-file? Maybe it got overwritten, and vhosts isn't enabled on your site?

Comment: yes I made a backup . what is the setting for enabling vhosts ?

Comment: the other thing I've noticed, is that the DocumentRoot has changed from /var/www to /var/www/html.  I've moved my site there and updtated vhost, but no luck

Comment: regarding vhost, I just checked. It's used to be Include sites-enabled/

and now it is IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf

Comment: Unbelievable.... I think I've fixed the problem. Thanks to you, I have checked the old config file and like I said above, they have changed the vhost configuration. Now it is expecting to have vhost file with .conf extension

Comment: Right. Wasn't aware of that, but glad to see you found something. I see the site mentioned above is up and running again.